# Underscore, clear all values of an object but keep keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know if this is possible but what I'm attempting to do is "clean" an object. The basic Idea is I hve a table feeding of an object (in angular) and on click I want to add a new row (a new item in the controlling object, but I want it to have no values in it. I have underscore to play around with. Some considerations are that the object coming in is going to have different key values each time, so I'm trying to keep this polymorphic (if possible).

So this is what I have so far :

```
<!-- model here for faces, could potentially not be seperate model and read off a length -->
        <div class="inputRepeater" ng-repeat="face in inputFaces" ng-show="face.isCurrent" >
            <div class="trialGrid" ng-init="$faceIndex = $index">
                <table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- table headers here - this can change if keys are not table exactly table headers with a bit of logic to change table headers to correct titles -->
                        <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in rowCollection[0]">{{key}}</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <!-- limit length by current face index + 1 -->
                    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection | limitTo: $faceIndex + 1" ng-class=" { 'curentRowTab2' : $index == $faceIndex }">
                        <td ng-repeat="item in row">{{item}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="stateTab2Progress"><div class="tab2ShiftLeft" ng-click="faceLeft($index)" ng-show="!$first"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></div><div class="progessTitle">Title</div><div class="progessCurrent">Current Progression {{$index + 1}}/{{inputFaces.length}}</div><div class="tab2ShiftRight" ng-show="!$last" ng-click="faceRight($index)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div><div class="tab2ShiftRight" ng-show="$last" ng-click="faceRightLast($index)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div></div>
            <div class="state2Buttons">Buttons Also Built dynamically</div>
            <button class="tab2Finish" ng-click="startTab3()">Finish</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So the click right (last) function is only shown if you are on the last object looks like so

```
$scope.faceRightLast = function(index){
    //copy current row and empty so we keep a polymorphic format, then add it onto current object, thus adding new empty object
    var storeRow = $scope.inputFaces[index];
    //push new face on face tracking array
    $scope.inputFaces.push({'isCurrent' : false });

    storeRow - clear values out?

    //after we have a fresh row change the is current
    $scope.inputFaces[index].isCurrent = false;
    $scope.inputFaces[index + 1].isCurrent = true;
}
```

So I'm making a copy of the current level, which I would then like to clean out the values and keep the keys then push onto the object.

Is something like this possible or should I figure out a new approach.

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need properties if they are empty? what should the value be?

Comment: @dandavis a fresh empty row, so no values if possible

Comment: @ajmajmajma instead of copying the current object, might a better solution be to make a function that returns an  object with all values set as null,  then whenever you need a new object, you can call that function?

Comment: I agree with @PatrickGunderson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newObject = angular.copy(oldObject);

for(var key in newObject){
    if(newObject.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        newObject[key] = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newObject = _.object(_.keys(oldObject));

_.object(_.keys({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}))
// Object {a: undefined, b: undefined, c: undefined}
```