# How to erase only the values of an object?

Tags: javascript, key, iteration

I have the following object:

```
obj = {"foo":"bar", "foo2":"bar2", "foo3":"bar3"};
```

I've been trying with a few iterations but haven't been able to catch the values (bar, bar2, bar3), only the keys.

What I need to do is to clear those values, so the keys happen to be all empty.

I've tried the following:

```
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  delete value;
// or also: value = '';
});
```

And also stuff like:

```
$(obj).each(function (key,value) -- //same content as last one.

Object.values(obj).forEach(function (key) {
  var value = obj[key];
});
```

Comment: Can you show the iterations you've tried so we can help you?

Comment: `empty`? -> null -> undefined -> '' -> 0 ?

Comment: If you have the keys you also have the values: `var val = obj[key]` (or the other way round)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underscore, clear all values of an object but keep keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097146/underscore-clear-all-values-of-an-object-but-keep-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through that object and set the value to `null`/`undefined` or whatever you want as empty value.

```js
var obj = {"foo":"bar", "foo2":"bar2", "foo3":"bar3"};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => { obj[k] = null; })

console.log(obj);
```

Or if you want to remove the key, use `delete`:

```js
var obj = {"foo":"bar", "foo2":"bar2", "foo3":"bar3"};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => { delete obj[k]; })

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This actually worked. But I would like to fully understand this kind of iteration with an "=>". Could you explain it to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is just es6 arrow function

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this by looping:

```js
var test = {"a":"abc", "b":"ref", "c": "def"}

console.log("Before:");
console.log(test);
 
for (var key in test) {
   test[key] = "";
}
console.log("After:");
console.log(test);
```